# JDK8 minimal Jasper compiler version

Tags: java-8

what is the minimal version of jasper-compiler.jar file and servlet-api.jar required, for avoiding compile time errors with **JDK8** ?

I am getting following Errorlogs when compiled with JDK8:
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

Generated servlet error:
The type java.util.regex.Pattern cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Generated servlet error:
The import java.util.regex.Pattern cannot be resolved

Comment: It seems that you have your classpath messed up. The Pattern class is there since Java 1.4.

Comment: No its not the issue with the classpath. The same thing works fine with JDK7. I have searched through the net, which conveys that its a JDK8 bug and the servlet api jar must be updated. But i m not sure of the version. Can you help me in getting the minimal version information of the jasper-compiler jars and servlet-api jar?

Comment: It would be really nice if people who are sure that something really is a JDK bug would either tell what the existing bug's ID in the JDK bugtracker is, or report a new bug if it hasn't been reported yet. Why do people always expect bugs to get solved that are never reported?

Comment: That being said, what version are you on? From what I found on the net, it looks rather like a Jasper issue than a JDK bug. Maybe this [answer](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1046301/jdk-18-jasperreport-47) on the jasper forums can help you. It says the minimal version is 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found it in the [TIBCO JasperReports Server v6.1.0 Release Notes](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/tibco-jasperreports-server-v610-release-notes):

> - **New Platform Support**
>
>   JasperReports Server now supports:
>
>   - Java 8 as a JDK